# Como usar uma váriavel de uma função async fora dela?

Tags: javascript

Eu quero usar a variável **data** fora da função **getData**.
Mesmo definindo a **data** em escopo global quando eu dou o console.log retorna undefined

```js
const apiURL = 'https://the-trivia-api.com/api/questions'; // Poderia ser qualquer uma
var data;

async function getData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    data = await response.json();
    console.log('Dentro da função:', data); // Retorna a resposta da API
}

getData(apiURL);
console.log('Fora da função:', data); // Retorna undefined
```

Comment: Desculpa qualquer erro, é minha primeira pergunta

Comment: Se criou uma função assíncrona e precisa de informações interna da função em código síncrono considere a possibilidade de ter feito algo errado. Funções bem projetadas não dependem de estados externos(variáveis globais), trocam informações com o escopo superior apenas pelos parâmetros e clausula/declaração de retorno. Veja o operador [`wait`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu sou iniciante e estou tentando usar API's no JavaScript essa foi a melhor estrutura que achei, valeu pela documentação, vou dar uma lida!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Voce tem que retornar um valor da função, e depois chamar a função externamente segue a correção.

```
const apiURL = 'https://the-trivia-api.com/api/questions'; // Poderia ser qualquer uma
var data;

async function getData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    data = await response.json();
    return data
}

const variavel = await getData(apiURL);
console.log('Fora da função:', variavel);
```

Resumindo a aplicação aguarda o termino da função getData, e encaminha para a variavel receber o valor do resultado.
assim podendo usar em qualquer instancia dora do função original.

nota que a função tem que retornar um valor, pode ser melhorada.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Copiei sua solução mas o console retorna o seguinte erro: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules (at script.js:10:18)'

Comment: se você for usar esse resultado você precisa de uma função pai,

Comment: Se você for usar o resultado para preencher o valor de algo cria uma função para receber o valor e usa um document.getElementById() ou querySelector para manipular no dom. ou salva os elemento em uma variavel global